# How can I extract values from a list?

Tags: python, list, extract

I am new to Python and am trying to achieve something new. I have a list defined with some string values, like

```
col_names = 'ABC,DEF,XYZ'.
```

If I want to extract and use values individually, how can I do that in Python?

Ex: I want to use ABC in one scenario but DEF in another and so on.

Can I create the list as a dictionary, like below? Would that help anything

```
col_names = {'ABC','DEF','XYZ'}
```

Comment: So you just want to split split the string on the commas? And that last example isn't a valid dictionary. Did you mean a set?

Comment: `col_names = 'ABC,DEF,XYZ'` is a string, not a list. Did you mean `col_names = ['ABC','DEF','XYZ']`?

Comment: I think you're looking for `split()` -- `col_names.split(',')`

Comment: The structure at the end of your question is a `set`, not a `dictionary`. You currently have a string that you refer to as a list. It might be better to take a step back here before proceeding to understand data types.

Comment: `col_names = {'ABC','DEF','XYZ'}` is a `set` **not** a `dict`, which normally looks like `d = {'key': 'value'}` or `d = dict(key='value')`

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

`col_names` is a string, not a list. You could use `col_names.split(',')` to separate each value.

FYI, the your second definition for `col_names` is a `set`, not a `dictionary`.

To use values from a list, you'd reference each value's index

For example, in a list `ls = ['ABC','DEF','XYZ']`, `ls[2]` would be equal to `'XYZ'`